# How to calculate a number like PI over multiple machines?

Tags: distributed-computing, pi

In what way would you try to use multiple computers to compute a number like PI, i.e.?

Are there existing algorithms or solutions that make this easy to do?
How do you split up the work and let the results from other machines come into effect?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one simple way:

1. generate a huge number of random (x,y) points where x and y are between 0 and 1.
2. for each point, calculate whether its cartesian distance to the origin is <= 1 (that is, whether it lies on or inside the circle)
3. count the number of point inside the circle versus outside the circle

Pi, then, can be calculated from the ratio of inside to outside points.  A very large number of points is necessary for this to approach pi, but if you have many machines, you can have each computer generate as many as you like, then simply return the counts to some leader machine, which would collect all the results and calculate the final ratio.

This method can be used to calculate pi to any precision you want...the more points, the more precision.  It's called a 'Monte Carlo' method because it uses randomness.  See http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/montecarlopimod.html for more information.

Comment: For this to really work (e.g. to get a good precision of pi), you also need to have high-precision random numbers, not only lots of them.

Answer (score 2):

An "easy" version would be using the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula, or its faster variant [Bellard Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellard%27s_formula). It allows calculating individual (binary) digits of π without calculating the previous ones before.

This means that you can distribute your calculation effort on different computers, which do not have to communicate much. For larger digit indices, you still need distribute the calculation even for a single digit (since you are doing some multiplications and divisions of really large integers).

This was used by the [PiHex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PiHex) project to calculate some (binary) digits around digit number 5·10<sup>12</sup>, some around 4·10<sup>13</sup> and some around 10<sup>15</sup>.

Answer (score -4):

On .Net platform, you can try .net remoting